# How do I rename file before sending

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor-pages, mailkit

I am using Mailkit with c# to send an email with an attachment.

How do I rename the attachment before sending the email?

I am currently using the code below but throws an error when deployed in IIS.

```
                var username = "username";
                var password = "password";
                var displayname = "display";

                var from = new MailboxAddress(displayname, username);
                var to = new MailboxAddress("User", emailto);

                msg.From.Add(from);
                msg.To.Add(to);

                msg.Subject = emailsubject;

                var attachment = new MimePart("application","zip")
                {
                    Content = new MimeContent(File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(fileutil.GetDir, "originalname.zip"))),
                    ContentDisposition = new ContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.Attachment),
                    ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.Base64,
                    FileName = "new filename.zip"
                };

                var msgbody = new BodyBuilder
                {
                    HtmlBody = string.Format(@"Message"),
                    TextBody = "Test Message!"
                };

                msgbody.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                msg.Body = msgbody.ToMessageBody();

                var client = new SmtpClient();
                client.Connect("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
                client.Authenticate(username, password);

                client.Send(msg);
                client.Disconnect(true);
                client.Dispose();
```

Edit: After a bit of digging, I found out that this is the exception thrown

````
The server's SSL certificate could not be validated for the following reasons:
• The server certificate has the following errors:
  • The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
  • The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.
• An intermediate certificate has the following errors:
  • The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
  • The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.```
````

Comment: What's the exception you get (and stacktrace)? Does it throw if you keep the original name?

Comment: @Fildor it throws a 500, `An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection`

Comment: ^^ regardless of whether you use "new name" or "originalname"? Looks like the problem is completely elsewhere: SSL/TLS.

Comment: @Fildor it works on my local IIS, also worked before putting the mimepart (to rename the attachment)

Comment: So, if you comment that part out again, it consitently works without attachment, and does not with?

Comment: @Fildor yes, works if i just use `msgbody.Attachments.Add("originalname.zip")`, but this will not allow to rename the file

Comment: That exception gets thrown by the SmtpClient before it does anything with the MimeMessage, so renaming the attachment is going to have 0 effect on whether connecting to the smtp server works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var client = new SmtpClient();
client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (o, c, ch, e) => true;
client.Connect("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
client.Authenticate(username, password);
```